# migrating from two ids to a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table that currently belongs to 2 different models. What I'd like to do is turn these into a polymorphic association instead.

Currently the table `line_items` have a `cart_id` and an `order_id` now what I'd like to do is migrate both of these ids into a polymorphic one called `itemable_id` and fix the `itemable_type` to the correct one.

How would I go about creating a migration for this, or what's the go-to solution for this case, where you have two ids columns and want to make it polymorphic?

Comment: Do you need to keep the records relation that already exists?

Comment: yes that's the catch

Answer (score 0):

Try following and add `belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true` in `LineItem` model

```
  rails generate migration RemoveCartRefFromLineItems cart:references
  rails generate migration RemoveOrderRefFromLineItems order:references
  rails g migration AddItemableIdToLineItems itemable_id:integer
  rails g migration AddItemableTypeToLineItems itemable_type:string
```